# Detect if an object is exactly a specific type and not a subclass of that type in swift

Tags: types, swift, conditional-statements

In swift you can check if an object is of a specific type using something similar to the following

```
let object: AnyObject = someOtherObject
if object is SKNode {
   //is SKNode
}
```

In this case SKShapeNode and SKSpriteNode would also satisfy this condition as they subclass SKNode.

What is the standard way to detect if an object is of a specific type and not a subclass of that type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Apple-approved way to do this in Swift 2.2 is:

```
if object.dynamicType === SKNode.self {
   // is node
}
```

and once [this proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md) is implemented (Swift 3.0), it will change to:

```
if object.Self === SKNode.self {
   // is node
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You could fall back to Objective-C:

```
if (object as AnyObject).isMemberOfClass(SKNode) {
   //is SKNode
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ashely, this does work for my scenario and is swift code, even if falling back to objective-c methods.

Comment: Note that this even works with native Swift classes (as long as `Foundation` is imported)

Answer (score 4):

This is not how the `is` operator works. If you do that, you'll get a compile error.

The `is` operator is used to check whether an object of a particular type is of a given sub-type. Using `SKNode` and `SKShapeNode` as examples, you'd use `is` to verify whether a object typed as `SKNode` is an `SKShapeNode` or an `SKSpriteNode`.

Paste this into a playground to get an idea of how it works:

```
let shape: SKNode = SKShapeNode()
let sprite: SKNode = SKSpriteNode()
let anotherShape = SKShapeNode()

if shape is SKShapeNode {
    println("is shape")
}

if sprite is SKSpriteNode {
    println("is sprite")
}

if shape is SKNode {
    //this raises a compile error, because the test is always true
}

if anotherShape is SKNode {
    //this raises a compile error, because SKNode is not a subtype of SKShapeNode
}
```

Comment: the test is not always true if the variable is of type AnyObject

Comment: My example is very specific. If you paste the code above into a playground, you will get the exact results described above.

Comment: Thanks for the response Cezar, I wasn't trying to discount the truth in what you said.  In my case the object was of type AnyObject not SKNode so no such compile error exists for me.

Comment: I have updated the question to stipulate the type of the object variable.

Answer (score 2):

In swift 3:

```
if type(of: object) == SKNode.self {
   // is node
}
```